# Capitalize text between parentheses in pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas column that contains a list of text:

```
["apple", "orange (fruit)", "banana"]
```

I would like to capitalize the text between the parentheses of the text so that the final output would be:

```
["apple", "orange (FRUIT)", "banana"]
```

Comment: Will there always be parenthesis around a string ()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Series.str.replace` with a regular expression:

```py
col.str.replace(r"\(.+\)", lambda x: x.group(0).upper(), regex=True)
```

This outputs:

```py
0             apple
1    orange (FRUIT)
2            banana
```